# pandas df.any() method returns True/False instead of NaN expected

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get into pandas so I work on some free data from kaggle.
Basically, I have a DataFrame, with few rows with only NaN's. I want to create new column using df.any(). I expect it to return True or False in other rows, but here is something I can't understand (and be sure I spent about 2 days of debugging, reading all documentations, online testing, forums, even stackoverflow, etc. before I decided to write this question):

1. If I run the same code in online jupyter editor, df.any(axis=1, skipna=False) do as follows:

- for rows containing at least one True value, it returns True to new column
- for rows with no True value (but some other values are there) it returns False to new column
- for rows that contain only NaN's, it returns NaN in new column

THIS IS THE BEHAVIOR I EXPECTED AND I WANT (ABOVE)

2. If I copy the code from online jupyter editor and run it local on my notebook, the result looks like this:

- for rows containing at least one True value, it returns True to new column
- for rows with no True value (but some other values are there) it returns False to new column
- for rows that contain only NaN's, it returns:

  - True, if I set the "skipna=False"
  - False, if I don't use "skipna=False", which basically means it's True due to documenation.

I thought I am insane (I guess you understand the stage of my insanity at this point), but as the data are free, I am posting few screens to show you.

[image]

[image]

In both cases above, I expect NaN values in column 'dissatisfied'.

Ofcourse, I simplified the description a bit to make my point at least clearer. What I really try (as can be seen on screenshots), I am creating new column ['dissatisfied'] by inspecting only two columns ['Contributing Factors. Dissatisfaction', 'Contributing Factors. Job Dissatisfaction'] with df.any() method. Still, I expect returns as NaN's for those rows.
But I get this output only online, but not using jupyter on my notebook.
Read all of the documentation. I don't think it's causedby different pandas versions. df.any() should NEVER for ANY version return True/False for rows containing only NaN's due to my research.

Can you guys please explain this? Or am I really missing something what is causing this? You will make my weekend much easier if you can provide explanation/solution to this.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you are using different versions of Python or pandas. In the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) you can check the behavior of the `any` method for various versions.